# In python subprocess, is Popen.kill() a blocking call or not?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

The docs only say that Popen.kill() sends SIGKILL to the child. 
Will the parent process wait until the child is killed or it just proceeds event if the child hasn't been killed?
How can I make sure that the child is killed?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill